# Git-backed ORM for Python?

Tags: python, database, git

While looking for information about versioned databases, I came across the [gitmodel](https://github.com/pauldowman/gitmodel) project for Ruby, which is a versioned ORM on top of git.

There are a few projects I'm involved in that could benefit from some sort of versioned data store, and Git seems like a natural solution in this space.  Our team is already familiar both with the git command line tools and the use of programmatic interfaces to git, such as [dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/), so something like [gitmodel](https://github.com/pauldowman/gitmodel) would play to our existing experience.

Is there anything similar available for Python?

Comment: Close votes for off-topic? If this isn’t related to programming or software development, I’ve no idea what it *is* related to.

Comment: Could, um, one of you folks who voted to close this question leave a comment indicating what part of the question you think is off topic?  Because if you're not willing to comment, I can't fix it!

Comment: Seems like a legit question to me...

Comment: I didn't try to close this out, but I think the line that's been getting people is 'It looks like an interesting idea.'

Comment: With that many do-not-close comments it should be easy to reopen the question if it really gets closed.

Comment: ok, removed the "looks like an interesting idea".  questions are closed here way too quickly.  just been reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264839/is-there-an-amazon-or-other-service-where-i-can-post-a-string-and-get-a-respon for example...

Comment: Well, the answer to this question is probably "no," at least according to a quick googling. It's a cool idea though, and maybe someone will write one. :)

Comment: I didn't, and wouldn't, vote to close this question. However, I do (think I) understand the people who do. StackOverflow exists for programmers to get help with programming from programmers. Asking "does a software package that does X exist" and similar existential questions isn't really asking for programming help - it's a knowledge search, not a technical question. The answer isn't technical, it's simply "have you encountered thing X for which I am looking". So, although it is quantitative, it's still not really the right *sort* of question...

Comment: Hello all, OP here again; I wanted to thank everyone who took a moment to leave constructive comments.  It's a lot more helpful than just voting to close and moving on!

Comment: I never knew git was relational !   learn something new every day.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite see the response by Borealid, which I think describes the problem with this question perfectly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I think I've addressed all the issues raised with the original question.  I believe Borealid's comment was helpful, but hopefully I've improved the question.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what I'm looking for, but I found [gitshelve](http://newartisans.com/2008/05/using-git-as-a-versioned-data-store-in-python/), which implement a git-backed `shelve`-like interface. The code may offer a starting point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: gotcha, I see the point.

Comment: Close status currently being discussed on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131385/140951

Answer (score 4):

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams pointed me towards the 
[django-versions](https://github.com/nowells/django-versions/) package, which while not based on git *does* offer a good model for storing versioned data.  I haven't had the opportunity to work with Django before, but this look as if it may be the best available option right now.

According to the documentation this may not work with the latest version of Django (the documentation says it requires 1.1.x, while Django is up to 1.4 for realz and 1.3 in my distribution's package repository).  I guess I'll look at it as a learning experience and see how much work is required to integrate it with more recent Django releases...

Answer (score 3):

Fresh from the oven, but you can take a look at [python-git-orm](https://github.com/natano/python-git-orm/).